# Trying to create a file with Filesystem

Tags: php, symfony

When I submit a form, I create a json with the information from the form. Then I try to write this information in a file but I've got some difficulties to do it.
I use `Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem` then I use dumpFile :
`$filesystem->dumpFile('%kernel.project_dir%/src/Json/file.json', $jsonContent)`.
The folder Json already exist, if I dump the $jsonContent I've got the information but the file is never created.

What I do wrong ?

Comment: use a try and catch block to see the exception, i guess its write permissions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Filesystem` component will not expand parameters like `%kernel.project_dir%`. You have to retrieve the project directory from dependency injection, then use it to build your whole path:

```
// Get the project directory in a way or another:
$projectDir = $kernel->getProjectDir();

// Store your file:
$fs = new Filesystem();
$fs->dumpFile("$projectDir/src/Json/file.json", 'Hello World');
```

### Some ways to get the project directory

#### 1. By using services.yaml

Add this into your services.yaml:

```yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            $projectDirectory: "%kernel.project_dir%"
```

Then you can inject your project directory by naming a parameter `$projectDirectory` in the contructor of a service/controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;

class HomeController
{
    public function index(string $projectDirectory): Response
    {
        // Store your file:
        $fs = new Filesystem();
        $fs->dumpFile("$projectDirectory/src/Json/file.json", 'Hello World');

        return new Response();
    }
}
```

#### 2. By injecting `KernelInterface`

It is less advised in our days:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class HomeController
{
    public function index(KernelInterface $kernel): Response
    {
        $projectDirectory = $kernel->getProjectDir();

        // Store your file:
        $fs = new Filesystem();
        $fs->dumpFile("$projectDirectory/src/Json/file.json", 'Hello World');

        return new Response();
    }
}
```